# Flask and .svg picture not show

Tags: python, svg, flask

I started to work with python - Flask and I found some problems which i didn't solve.

When I want show picture in .svg format so it doesn't show in flask but when i open html file (index.html) in for example Firefox it showed!
Code in Flask template:
 
when i show source code (in flask server) it is [image: logo]. Link /static/img/logo-landing.svg is found but image doesn't show. It show only alt ('logo')

I don't know what is wrong. I was use google full last night.
Thanks Mike

Comment: What is the Content-Type of your svg-file?

Comment: here is one of pictures https://www.dropbox.com/s/67pixjx4qcgkv0o/logo-landing.svg?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to serve your svg-images with Content-Type `image/svg+xml`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/svg_returned_endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def svg_returned_endpoint():
    # HTML version
    # this gets the json object from the user
    json_obj = {'input_1': request.values['input_1']}
    input_1_item = json_obj["input_1"]
    
    # normal endpoint version
    # this gets the json object from the user
    json_obj = request.get_json(force=True)
    input_1_item = json_obj["input_1"]
    
    ####
    ## Your Actual function/model Code Goes Here
    ####

    filename = 'YOUR_SAVED_IMAGE.svg'
    
    return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/svg+xml')
```